# Riesz Representation Theorem from Bartle

Tags: measure-theory

> [image]

This is proof of Riesz Representation theorem from Bartle. I don't understand one step in this proof. The author shows that $\lambda$ is a measure, but I am not sure how the highlighted line shows that it is. I guess the highlighted line is related to the countable additivity, but I can't see it does. I appreciate if you give some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove countable additivity, it suffices to prove continuity from below, namely that if $E = \cup_n E_n$ where $E_1 \subseteq E_2 \subseteq \dots$, then $\lim_n \mu(E_n) = \mu(E)$.

Comment: Oh, then  since $\lim ||\chi_E  - \chi_{E_n}||_1 = 0$, $\lim \lambda(E) - \lambda(E_n) = 0$?

Comment: obviously.. you should know squeeze theorem or whatever it's called

Comment: Oh, I forgot to accept. Thanks!